# How to build a node module?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, webdriver-io

I thought this would be trivial and I realise that it may differ from project to project, but I tried to reproduce the node module build for [webdriverio](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio) locally and use that in my project.

Here's what I tried:

```
git clone git@github.com:webdriverio/webdriverio.git
cd webdriverio
git checkout v4.8.0
npm install
npm run build
npm pack
```

This produces a file named `webdriverio-4.8.0.tgz`. I change the `package.json` file of my project to depend on this file rather than `webdriverio` from `npm`. Like so:

```
"webdriverio": "file:../webdriverio/webdriverio-4.8.0.tgz",
```

Running `npm install` in my project, updates `webdriverio` in `node_modules` as expected, except my version is different from the `npm` version, despite presumably being based on the same code.

I've never built a node module before, so I appreciate that I might have missed something, but the resources I've found online seem to indicate that the above should be enough. Also if there is a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish, I'd appreciate the feedback.

Comment: what do you mean by  _except my version is different from the npm version_? what is the _npm version_ and _your version_?

Comment: Also, on another point, why do you want it to be local? Would you have an issue with publishing the module and installing it from the registry?

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa I did a diff on my version and the npm version and the diff file is over 500 lines. Haven't had time to fully analyse it, but something in there is causing my build to crash when I try to use it.

Comment: The problem was probably with my environment. In the end, I made it work with the exact commands provided above.